# Отрисовки пирамиды с числами в консоли

Tags: java

```
char [] s = Main.str.toCharArray();
for (int i = 1; i < Main.str.length()+1; i++){
System.out.print(" ");
}
System.out.println("^");
for (int i = 1; i < Main.str.length(); i++){
System.out.print(" ");
}
if(Main.str.length() == 4){ 
  for (int i = 0; i < Main.str.length()/2; i++){ //стр - это та строка, в которой число, далее будет переведена в чар
    for (int j = 0; j < i+1; j++){ 

     System.out.print("/" + s[i] + " \\ "); 
    } 
    System.out.println(); 
     for (int sp = 1; sp < Main.str.length()-1; sp++){ 
      System.out.print(" "); 
     } 
   } 
 } 
 else{ 
 for (int i = 0; i < Main.str.length()/4; i++){ 

  for (int j = 0; j < i+1; j++){ 

   System.out.print("/" + s[i] + "\\ "); 
  } 
  System.out.println(); 
   for (int sp = 1; sp < Main.str.length()-1; sp++){ 
    System.out.print(" "); 
   } 
 } 
 }
```

Пытаюсь отрисовать пирамиду, заполненную числами из чаровского массива. Что не так?
Количество цифр в числе 4^n[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а проблема в чем ? и будьте добры, приложите Main.str или полный воспроизводимый код.

Comment: Неправильно выводятся значения

Comment: И числа не выводятся в треугольники с вершиной, смотрящей вниз

Comment: приложите к телу поросу ожидаемый и фактический результат

Comment: Прикрепил фото нужного результата

Comment: в вашем примере не определена переменная `s[i]`

Comment: char [] s = Main.str.toCharArray();

Answer (score 0):

у вас неверно печатались символы, добавил `sp < Main.str.length() - 1 - i` и поменял местами печать

```
static String str = "01010101011101010010101010001001001001010101000100100100";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] s = str.toCharArray();
    if (Main.str.length() == 4) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Main.str.length() / 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {

                System.out.print("/" + s[i] + " \\ ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            for (int sp = 1; sp < Main.str.length() - 1; sp++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < Main.str.length() / 4; i++) {
            System.out.println();
            for (int sp = 0; sp < Main.str.length() - 1 - i; sp++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {

                System.out.print("/" + s[i] + "\\ ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

вывод

```
                                                   /0\ 
                                                  /1\ /1\ 
                                                 /0\ /0\ /0\ 
                                                /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ 
                                               /0\ /0\ /0\ /0\ /0\ 
                                              /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ 
                                             /0\ /0\ /0\ /0\ /0\ /0\ /0\ 
                                            /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ 
                                           /0\ /0\ /0\ /0\ /0\ /0\ /0\ /0\ /0\ 
                                          /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ 
                                         /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ 
                                        /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ 
                                       /0\ /0\ /0\ /0\ /0\ /0\ /0\ /0\ /0\ /0\ /0\ /0\ /0\ 
                                      /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\ /1\
```

p.s. не очень понятно, почему `Main.str.length() / 4`, таким образом вы печатаете четверть строки

Comment: Я так понимаю, пирамида заполняется сверху вниз, да?

Comment: да, сверху печатается

Comment: А мне же нужно справа налево, начиная снизу и чтобы между \/ также были числа, т.е. не было пустого пространства

Comment: я ответил на вопрос `Что не так? `, то , что вы хотите, нужно подробно описать в новом  вопросе.

Comment: "хочу \/ также были числа", `out.print("/" + s[i] + " \\ ")` определяет как будет выглядеть вывод

Comment: Описал в новом вопросе